# "По полной" / "на полную"

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология

1) *Использовал (шанс, возможность, и т.п.) по полной.*

2) *Использовал (шанс, возможность, и т.п.) на полную.*

Оба ли варианта правильны? (Насчёт первого есть некоторые сомнения). Если оба правильны - есть ли между ними какая-нибудь разница?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При всей неформальности обоих выражений, с высокой вероятностью они происходят от сокращенных сочетаний с *существительным* (ср. мороженое */блюдо/*, слизистая */оболочка/*). Поэтому для оценки **сочетаемости** рассматриваемого выражения с "использованием шанса" можно попытаться восстановить существительное для каждого варианта. Что могло быть исходным вариантом в первом случае? "*По полной **схеме***" - такое выражение с "использованием шанса" худо-бедно может сочетаться (оно употребляется и в полной форме). Какое же существительное "выпало" из выражения "*на полную...*"? Напрашивается "*на полную **катушку, мощность***" (*запустить, включить*). Это обычно о звукоусилительной установке или машине (станке, электроинструменте) - с "шансами" выглядит неубедительно, поэтому из двух выражений я бы выбрал *первое*. Либо можно обойтись более формальным выражением "**в полной мере**".