# Я с ним на полную / наполную развеселилась

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Я с ним на полную / наполную развеселилась.

Comment: никак, потому что речевая ошибка. Веселилась по полной, включил двигатель на полную мощность. Развеселилась на полную - чушь какая-то. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/453582/По-полной-на-полную

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: ["По полной" / "на полную"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/453582/%d0%9f%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e)